# Daily reboot happens twice (cron)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I have created a cron job, which will reboot the system every day at 00:01 (AM), but as soon as the system comes back up and the cron daemon is back up (within the same minute) - another reboot occurs (which makes sense).

How can this be prevented without using a bash script that will sleep 24 hours? I am using Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS 64bit.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual code. Notice also the detailed troubleshooting instructions in [the Stack Overflow `cron` tag info page](/tags/cron/info).

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13730/how-can-i-schedule-a-nightly-reboot), you can just delay the reboot itself, which will solve your problem.

```
0 4   *   *   *    /sbin/shutdown -r +5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your system may reboot too fast.

```
sleep 60; reboot
```